Is there a way to 'infuse' model so transformer pruning didn't have to start from scratch?
Transformers are infamous for it's massive resources need to perform an impressive feat in NLP and currently also in image processing especially image segmentation. There is a trick called soft-token pruning so as the 'pruning-algorithm' cuts the unnecessary variables, for example the background of an image, the transformer won't have to train in full power.
But "..won't have to train in full power after several iteration" means it has a highest computation threshold at first training session, then it will lower as the token become pruned one by one, as it approached desired accuracy (yes you also have to know the ideal accuracy because the paper said it is selective based on training it did. So first iteration will give certain accuracy, then next training will have new accuracy, until it met desired accuracy?)
My question is, is there a way to 'infuse' a pretrained model to the transformer part so it doesn't have to 'train', but instead do 'inference', before pruning the token?
I have tried doing inference in whole new set of unpruned dataset and planned to train the other algorithm with the inferenced images. But from a question that has been asked about using trained images as a training data, this method is called semi-supervised training? Is it a valid method to 'infuse so the training doesn't have to go from peak'?
Sorry for lot's of confusing words I wish I know where I was going with this..
